# ETW Channel Providers - Channel Names

Tags: c#, etw

I am using latest EventSource Nuget-Package for creating eventlogs where every application gets its own folder for different types of logs.

As playing around I figured out that I can't simply change the logs name.
I tried to change it in the manifest file and registered the new channel where it displayed its new name. Unfortunately every event fired to these logs won't show up anymore till I register a new channel with predefined channel name.

Any chance to change that? Since I have to create manifest files on each machine i have to change it programatically because channel names were created by predefined values (Admin, Operational, etc...)

To be clear: I want to change following names AND have all logs written into these channels.

[image: Channels]

Sample-manifest which was generated automatically:

```
<instrumentationManifest xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events">
 <instrumentation xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:win="http://manifests.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/windows/events">
  <events xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events">
<provider name="Samples-EventSourceDemos-EventLog" guid="{d89ec17d-ee69-5275-eb6f-0c826bb76bd8}" resourceFileName="E:\EventlogTest\bin\Debug\EventlogTest.Samples-EventSourceDemos-EventLog.etwManifest.dll" messageFileName="E:\EventlogTest\bin\Debug\EventlogTest.Samples-EventSourceDemos-EventLog.etwManifest.dll" symbol="SamplesEventSourceDemosEventLog">
 <channels>
  <channel chid="Admin" name="Samples-EventSourceDemos-EventLog/Admin" value="16" type="Admin" enabled="true"/>
  <channel chid="Analytic" name="Samples-EventSourceDemos-EventLog/Analytic" value="18" type="Analytic" enabled="false"/>
  <channel chid="Debug" name="Samples-EventSourceDemos-EventLog/Debug" value="19" type="Debug" enabled="false"/>
 </channels>
 <tasks>
  <task name="Request" message="$(string.task_Request)" value="1"/>
  <task name="DebugTrace" message="$(string.task_DebugTrace)" value="65530"/>
 </tasks>
 <opcodes>
 </opcodes>
 <keywords>
  <keyword name="Requests" message="$(string.keyword_Requests)" mask="0x1"/>
  <keyword name="Debug" message="$(string.keyword_Debug)" mask="0x2"/>
  <keyword name="Session3" message="$(string.keyword_Session3)" mask="0x100000000000"/>
  <keyword name="Session2" message="$(string.keyword_Session2)" mask="0x200000000000"/>
  <keyword name="Session1" message="$(string.keyword_Session1)" mask="0x400000000000"/>
  <keyword name="Session0" message="$(string.keyword_Session0)" mask="0x800000000000"/>
 </keywords>
 <events>
  <event value="1" version="0" level="win:Error" symbol="RequestStart" message="$(string.event_RequestStart)" keywords="Requests" opcode="win:Start" task="Request" channel="Admin" template="RequestStartArgs"/>
  <event value="2" version="0" level="win:Error" symbol="RequestPhase" message="$(string.event_RequestPhase)" keywords="Requests" task="Request" channel="Analytic" template="RequestPhaseArgs"/>
  <event value="3" version="0" level="win:Error" symbol="RequestStop" message="$(string.event_RequestStop)" keywords="Requests" opcode="win:Stop" task="Request" channel="Admin" template="RequestStopArgs"/>
  <event value="4" version="0" level="win:Error" symbol="DebugTrace" message="$(string.event_DebugTrace)" keywords="Debug" task="DebugTrace" channel="Debug" template="DebugTraceArgs"/>
 </events>
 <templates>
  <template tid="RequestStartArgs">
   <data name="RequestID" inType="win:Int32"/>
   <data name="Url" inType="win:UnicodeString"/>
  </template>
  <template tid="RequestPhaseArgs">
   <data name="RequestID" inType="win:Int32"/>
   <data name="PhaseName" inType="win:UnicodeString"/>
  </template>
  <template tid="RequestStopArgs">
   <data name="RequestID" inType="win:Int32"/>
  </template>
  <template tid="DebugTraceArgs">
   <data name="Message" inType="win:UnicodeString"/>
  </template>
 </templates>
</provider>
</events>
</instrumentation>
<localization>
 <resources culture="de-DE">
  <stringTable>
   <string id="event_DebugTrace" value="DebugMessage: %1"/>
   <string id="event_RequestPhase" value="Entering Phase %2 for request %1"/>
   <string id="event_RequestStart" value="Start processing request%n%t*** %1 ***%nfor URL%n%t=== %2 ==="/>
   <string id="event_RequestStop" value="Stop processing request%n%t*** %1 ***"/>
   <string id="keyword_Debug" value="Debug"/>
   <string id="keyword_Requests" value="Requests"/>
   <string id="keyword_Session0" value="Session0"/>
   <string id="keyword_Session1" value="Session1"/>
   <string id="keyword_Session2" value="Session2"/>
   <string id="keyword_Session3" value="Session3"/>
   <string id="task_DebugTrace" value="DebugTrace"/>
   <string id="task_Request" value="Request"/>
  </stringTable>
 </resources>
</localization>
</instrumentationManifest>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because there are different logs for specified events. It's not only to look better but for identification. There will be about 20-30 different logs in some folders. That's why I need to rename them to have more logs and not to waste hours looking for specific entries

Comment: according to this you can have only those predefined channels: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd996911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx **"The channel must be of one of four types: Admin, Operational, Analytic, and Debug"**

Comment: Yeah, I know. But it is possible to rename them. You can simply modify the manifest to change the names and the logs will be created with that name. But they will still log into the channel which has the same name as it's type defined